# Linux directories

Tags: linux, unix, installation, packaging, directory

I am writing installation script for my program, which is supposed to run on Linux/Unix OS. What is the default directory for the following files:

1. Executable files (programs). Program should be executed by typing its name from the command line.
2. Shared libraries.
3. Third-party shared libraries (the program is not open source, so I need to redistribute third-party libraries).
4. Read-only program configuration files for all users.
5. Configuration data available for read/write access for all users.

Comment: Useful: http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Comment: @Migrators: This doesn't seem appropriate for SuperUser, since it's about how to *write an installation program*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The listing varies depending on the Linux filesystem.

1) `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`

2/3) `/lib`, `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib`

<strike>3. `/usr/share/lib`</strike>

4) `/etc` is a read-only spot for configuration data.

5) `/usr/local/etc` or usually in the `/home` directory under the dot directory name, if the profile allows the bin directory to be located under the `/home/user_id/bin` where 'user_id' is the relevant login id.. for an example for user 'jdoe', his configuration could be written to `/home/jdoe/.configs` or `~/.configs`

Do not rely on this, for the most part the LSB filesystem dictates that there shall be at minimum:
`/bin`, `/etc`, `/usr`, `/lib`, `/home`

For instance, the `/usr` could be on a different partition, likewise the same for `/home`

**Edit:** Thanks to ***dtrosset*** for pointing out my blooper....

Comment: NO! /usr/share is for files than can be shared by multiple architectures (i686, amd64, ppc, armel ...) such as images, or documentation. It is not for shared libraries that should go as 2).

Comment: /etc is read-only on my Ubuntu computer, what directory is available for read/write access for all users, like Documents and Settings\All Users in Win XP?

Comment: @Alex: The other spot can be /usr/local/etc

Comment: @Alex: In general it is considered a bad idea if one user can arbitrarily affect how a program runs for another user (special cases like the high score table in games are usually handled with a setgid executable).  If you *really* need this, you can always create (at install-time) an `/etc/<appname>` directory for your application, and a `/etc/<appname>/all-users` directory or config file that is world-writeable.  It still seems like a bad idea though (on XP the "All Users" folder is only writeable by Administrators and Power Users by default).

Answer (score 3):

1. `$PREFIX/bin`
2. `$PREFIX/lib`
3. `$PREFIX/lib`
4. `/etc`
5. `$HOME/.config`

Where `$HOME` is the home directory of the user running the application, determined at runtime.  `$PREFIX` depends on the method of distribution:

- If distributed as source, `$PREFIX` should be configurable but default to `/usr/local`;
- If distributed as a binary tarball, `$PREFIX` should usually be `/usr/local` (but `/opt` is also common);
- If distributed as a distribution package (eg RPM or DPKG), `$PREFIX` should be `/usr`.

Documentation and other architecture-independent files should go in `$PREFIX/share/doc`; program-generated files shared between instances should go in `/var/run` (things like lockfiles, pidfiles and sockets) or `/var/lib` (things like shared binary databases).

Comment: Right. And apropos of the OPs comments, if you don't have root privileges you install in $HOME and update your various path variable to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html).

Answer (score 1):

Executable (Binary):

- /bin/
- /usr/bin/
- /home/~user/bin/

Shared:

- /usr/share/

Other:

- /etc/

I'm not sure it would be wise to be writing an install script if you don't know the file structure of a *nix OS. Besides which, each distribution of *nix is sligthly different when it comes to where the data is stored.

I suggest you read this:
http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/commands/linux_crfilest.html

^.^

Comment: NO! /usr/share is for files than can be shared by multiple architectures (i686, amd64, ppc, armel ...) such as images, or documentation. It is not for shared libraries that should go as 2).

Comment: +1 for the link but you should mention that user programs must not go into /bin

Comment: Apologies all round, first answer of the morning - please forgive me :'( - Cheers for the +1 though!

Comment: Neurofluxation, thank you for useful link. /etc is read-only on my Ubuntu computer, what about read/write access for all users?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to make an `.rpm` of your application and then use for example `alien` to make an `.deb` out of it. Last I made a deb, it was really, really simple. The packaging also enables you to have a sorts-of auto-update if you want to enable it and you will not need to think a lot about uninstallation procedures.